# Destination "does not exist" error on EAP 7.2

Tags: java, jms, jboss-eap-7, activemq-artemis

We have a fully configured environment running our application on EAP 7.1. I used the migration tool to migrate our configurations to 7.2. Once I start the application and it tries to validate the destinations it fails on the first one immediately.

The queue is configured in `hornetq-jms.xml`, but I am still getting the error:

```
javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Destination GIVENQUEUE does not exist
```

Is there any immediate configuration change that comes to mind under the 7.1 -> 7.2 migration? I did not tweak anything at this point, only automatic migration.

This is for a JBoss 7.2 running on a Domain environment.

Comment: The JMS implementation in both EAP 7.1 and 7.2 is ActiveMQ Artemis. The `hornetq-jms.xml` shouldn't be used. How are you using this configuration file? Can you share your server XML config file?

Comment: XML config file could be considered the default configuration for JBoss, at this point we have nothing configured that should be relevant for this queue. The queue is declared on the hornetq-jms.xml file, and if I interpreted correctly the documentation this name makes no difference, as long as it fits "*-jms.xml", which it does. I tried deploying a cloned file, renaming it to activemq-jms.xml, and when doing so, I got an error due to Queue already being registered. So the file seems to be interpreted correctly, but then it states that Destination does not exist. Any idea ?